# my hashmap is string and list of string type then how can I fetch value of the list?

Tags: android

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     final String value=(String)(getChild(groupPosition,childPosition));

        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exp_child_layout, parent, false);
        }

        TextView txt_group_category = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_child_category);

        txt_group_category.setText("test");

        return view;
    }
```

but it gives me `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Please post your error code that you have got in logcat.

Comment: post the code for getChild() method

Answer (score 0):

This is my code jus for your reference, I have implemented Expandable ListView and i have the same scenario that I have a string as Group Header and against it I have saved my ArrayList for children

In `getChild()`  first I got the name from another ArrayList then getting its value from the HashMap. `If` clause checking that if the header contains the children.

```
@Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {

        if(this.inboxItem.containsKey(this.inboxHeaders.get(groupPosition)))
        return this.inboxItem.get(this.inboxHeaders.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosititon);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Inbox child = (Inbox) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if(child != null) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.inbox_item, null);
            }

            ImageView unreadMarker = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.unread_icon);
            TextView inboxTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.inbox_title);
            TextView inboxDesc = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.inbox_desc);

            if(child.getsDesc() != null && child.getfDesc() != null)
                unreadMarker.setImageResource(R.drawable.email_icon_unread);

            inboxTitle.setText(child.getpName());
            inboxDesc.setText(child.gettDesc());
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```